# Boy goes to magical boarding school

Tags: story-identification

It was an a magical world (without a sort of Harry Potter type ending). They went to boarding school and the bedrooms were magical and they made themselves to fit your personality. One boy that was a bully got a dungeon room and the main character (also a boy) had an entire world.

They had sports and the playing field would change around and during one game it changed into a giant hill and in the end the friends were doing something to get rid of the villain and ended up in...a cave or something?

I've been trying to find this book for years so anything would help.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151780/ya-novel-series-involving-magical-student-warrior

Answer (score 13):

That's [The Hound of Rowan](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/603515.The_Hound_of_Rowan?from_search=true) by Henry H. Neff.

> Max McDaniels lives a quiet life in the suburbs of Chicago, until the day he stumbles upon a mysterious Celtic tapestry. Many strange people are interested in Max and his tapestry. His discovery leads him to Rowan Academy, a secret school where great things await him.
>
> But dark things are waiting, too. When Max learns that priceless artworks and gifted children are disappearing, he finds himself in the crossfire of an ancient struggle between good and evil. To survive, he'll have to rely on a network of agents and mystics, the genius of his roommate, and the frightening power awakening within him.

Max and his roommate do indeed get an extremely spacious room since they're both "special".  Each set of roommates does get a personalized dorm.

Likewise, there is a version of soccer/football (sorta?) that has a field that changes elevations as you play.  Max is exceptionally good at it.

[image: cover from goodreads]

It's the first of 5:

1. The Hound Of Rowan (2007)
2. The Second Siege (2008)
3. The Fiend And The Forge (2010)
4. The Maelstrom (2012)
5. The Red Winter (2014)

They seem very Harry Potter-ish at first, but quickly change in books 2-5.